# Can I make hatch lines that are evenly spaced and contoured in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, blending

I’m learning to do [contoured cross hatching in illustrator](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/how-to/create-graphic-portraits.html)

Obviously if I create two lines at two angles and blend them, some areas are more densely spaced than others.  In a cross hatching context this breaks the rule of even shading.

I’m wondering if there’s a way to have more lines in areas farther apart so I can blend contour lines and maintain the same shading value when cross hatching.

Obviously if you’re making contour lines for a 3D object you’ll have this issue.

Is there any technique to do this?

An example might be tiger stripes which converge and end pretty randomly but there’s always a pretty even spacing between the stripes themselves

Comment: Blends often only go so far.. at some point you may need to expand them and manually alter things.

Comment: @Scott Yes, I woke up this morning and thought of Blend-, expand, blend with a different number of vectors, and then doing some boolean voodoo to get one blend to fill the spaces of the other.